# Shading specific area under a line using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to shade the area under my line plot so that only the area that has a y value that is greater than 0.5 (shown by the black horizontal line) is shaded.

This is my current code:

```
n = 256
X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, n, endpoint=True)
Y = np.sin(2 * X)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X, Y, color='blue', alpha=1.0)
ax.fill_between(X, 0, Y, color='blue', alpha=.2)
plt.axhline(0.5, color="black")
plt.show()
```

[image: Current plot]

This is what I want the plot to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `where` argument in `ax.fill_between` (doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between)) to achieve what you want. See code below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
            
n = 256
X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, n, endpoint=True)
Y = np.sin(2 * X)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X, Y, color='blue', alpha=1.0)
ax.fill_between(X,Y, 0.5,where=Y>0.5,color='blue', alpha=.2)
plt.axhline(0.5, color="black")
plt.show()
```

[image]